# android KeyEvent ACTION_MULTIPLE and getCharacters deprecation

Tags: android, keyevent, non-ascii-characters, deprecation-warning

According to the android docs, the KeyEvent *ACTION_MULTIPLE* (=2) constant and *getCharacters*() functions are deprecated at API 29. They claim these features are no longer used by the input system. I want to know the correct way to receive accented characters which the user types on the soft keyboard. Currently these come through in *onKeyMultiple()* with a *KeyEvent* with action code *ACTION_MULTIPLE*, and the *String* returned by *getCharacters*() contains the accented character. In fact, I am testing on a tablet running Android 10 (API 29) and this is exactly what happens, despite the statements to the contrary in the documentation. This is annoying because my code gets deprecation warnings, even though it works. For accented characters *onKeyUp*() is not called, only *onKeyMultiple*().

So is the documentation incorrect? I note also that the documentation does not explain how we *should* be receiving non-ascii characters such as European accented vowels. I might perhaps expect the *getUnicodeChar*() function to return the Unicode codepoint for the accented character, but this function just returns 0 for such characters. The *keyCode* argument is also 0 for non-ascii characters.

I am writing a native application using my own proprietory cross-platform engine. I am overriding the following functions in my java NativeActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    // When press 'e' get keyCode 33, action 1, and unicode char 101.
    // Not called for non-ascii characters
    Log.i( "MyApp", "onKeyUp " + keyCode );
    Log.i( "MyApp", "action " + event.getAction() );
    Log.i( "MyApp", "unicode " + event.getUnicodeChar() );

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyMultiple( int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event )
{
    // When type 'e' with grave accent get keyCode 0, action 2, unicode 0
    // and getCharacters() returns String containing the accented character.
    // only called for non-ascii characters.
    Log.i( "MyApp", "onKeyMultiple " + keyCode );
    Log.i( "MyApp", "action " + event.getAction() );
    Log.i( "MyApp", "unicode " + event.getUnicodeChar() );
    Log.i( "MyApp", "chars " + event.getCharacters() );
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just testing on a device running API 33 and the behaviour is still exactly as described above, and still no clue in the android documentation as to the 'correct', undeprecated way to receive accented characters